# Proving that the Jacobi and Gauss-Seidel converges in a $2\times2$ matrix

Tags: numerical-methods

Prove that for the system \begin{cases} ax+by=p\\ cx+dy=q \end{cases} a necessary and sufficient condition of convergence for the Jacobi and Gauss-Seidel iterative methods is $|bc|<|ad|$.

I have tried to prove it using that the iterative method converges if and only if its espectral radius is $\rho<1$ without succeeding, however I am pretty sure I should use that

Comment: Can you write down the relevant iteration matrices? Since everything is 2x2 you can calculate the spectral radius of such a matrix by hand.

Comment: @Ian I tried to calculate the eigenvalues and I have $\lambda_1=\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{a^2-2ad+4bc+d^2}+a+d)$ and $\lambda_2=\frac{1}{2}(-\sqrt{a^2-2ad+4bc+d^2}+a+d)$. I don't know how can I get to $|bc|<|ad|$ from here.

Comment: The Jacobi iteration matrix is $\begin{bmatrix} a & 0 \\ 0 & d \end{bmatrix}^{-1} \begin{bmatrix} 0 & b \\ c & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ while the Gauss-Seidel iteration matrix is $\begin{bmatrix} a & 0 \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}^{-1} \begin{bmatrix} 0 & b \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$. You need to compute the eigenvalues of each of these. You computed the eigenvalues of the *system* matrix, which do not really matter very much.

Comment: I intuitively see why the iteration matrix are these, and calculating the eigenvector for these matrix I get that $ab/cd$ must be $<1$. Where can I find a proof that the iteration matrices are like that?

Comment: It is the definition of the Jacobi and Gauss-Seidel methods. Jacobi writes $A=D+R$ where $D$ is diagonal and $R$ has zero diagonal entries to get $Ax=b$ equivalent to $(D+R)x=b$ equivalent to $x=D^{-1}(b-Rx)$. Gauss-Seidel writes $A=L+U$ where $L$ is lower triangular and $U$ is strictly upper triangular to get $Ax=b$ equivalent to $(L+U)x=b$ equivalent to $x=L^{-1}(b-Ux)$. So technically the iteration matrices are actually $-D^{-1}R$ and $-L^{-1}U$ but the minus sign doesn't change the spectral radius.